# How do I link stack exchange accounts?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

How do I link https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/189208/unknown-bliss account to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1247922/unknown-bliss to https://math.stackexchange.com/users/34480/unknown-bliss

Comment: Pretty sure you'll need an openID, meaning you'll sign in with your Google Account/facebook or register a new account through Stack Exchange. As-is you're unregistered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account on Mathematics is unregistered, and it cannot be linked to other registered accounts you have on other Stack Exchange sites.

[image: screenshot]

You need to register an account on Mathematics, using the same OpenID account you already used on Stack Overflow.

The accounts on Stack Overflow, and Meta Stack Overflow are already linked together.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think unregistered account have to be merged, for this he can flag one of his own posts.

Comment: There is no need to merge it. A user with an unregistered account see the "register" link on the top bar. Following that link, the account is changed in a registered account.

Comment: Nice didn't know that. +1 of course no idea who might disagree with you!